# Common class for Thread implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write a common class for thread implementation. I wanted to use this class to perform various bulk operations. Currently I have code for performing these operations one by one.
I wanted to avoid writing separate class for each type of operation for thread implementations, instead write a single class where i can just switch the main operation to be performed in thread dynamically.

Please tell what can be the best way to implement this

Comment: And what about using `Callable` and combine that with an `ExecutorService`?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable` and create some custom class   `BaseOperationThread`. Then you can create one or many subclasses of
`BaseOperationThread` which implement the various concrete operations that
you have. In `BaseOperationThread` you many have fields like e.g.
`String operationType`, `Object operationData` or similar.

See also:
[java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
[java.lang.Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

Comment: In general you should prefer implementing `Runnable` over extending `Thread`.